# AddEventListener Won't restart when page reloads

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have code that sets an `eventListener` when the page loads. The `eventListener` works fine, the first time.

I click on the `eventType` and the event fires off as expected. However, when I click on the navbar "home" button to start over. The `addEventListener` does not gets set and even when I click, the events do not fire off.

I've looked into removing `eventListener` and re-adding them, but I don't think that is the best solution.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  <ul id='listOfEventTypes'>
    <% @event_type.each do |type| %>
      <div data-event-type='<%= type['name'] %>' class="col-lg-4" id='eventType'>
        <li> <%= type['name'] %></li>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

---

```
(function() {
  function init() {
    bindEvents();
  }

  function bindEvents() {
    var eventType = document.getElementById('listOfEventTypes').children;

    for (var i = 0; i < eventType.length; i++) (function(n){
     eventType[n].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('what happened here');
     }, false);
    })(i);
  };
  $(document).ready(function() {
    init();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**Edit**

Added html

Comment: post html of listOfEventTypes, please

Comment: I think you don't actually reload the page, but use some single page framework, and the code you posted runs only at the *real* page load.

Comment: I'm using pure javascript and no framework for the single page. What i do notice is when I refresh the page it works fine again. but not when I do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using rails, it would be better that you explain project structure sepecialy location of javascript file.
I think your problem comes from [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks):

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
>   **Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body (or parts of) and the title in the head**.
>   Think CGI vs persistent process.

according to documentation, it is possible that your javascript code does not run for the second time.

as well as you should get jQuery in your function like this :

```
(function($) {...
```

Comment: could you tell me how the location of the JS file can affect this? Also does that mean you don't recommend I use Turbolinks?